# Custom updated_at for a specific field/attribute in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently have a method that increments an attribute on the `Subscriber`. It's visit attribute that takes in a int. My question is - Can I find that `Subscriber` that last had their visit attribute updated? In the console it would look something like this - `Subscriber.find("visit +=1").last` <- completely wrong BTW, but I assume it would look kinda like that? Does anybody know how I can call this in the console?? Any help would be great.

Controller Method:

```
def visit
  @subscriber = Subscriber.find_by(params[:phone_number])
  if @subscriber
    @subscriber.visit ||= 0
    @subscriber.visit += 1
    @subscriber.save
    flash[:notice] = flash[:notice] = "Thank You #{@subscriber.first_name}. You have #{@subscriber.days_till_expired} until renewal"
    redirect_to subscribers_search_path(:subscriber)
  else
    render "search"
  end
end
```

As you can see I would like to call the Subscriber who last used this method to update the visit attribute on their object. Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: unless you have a special timestamp field, that is updated only when the method above is called, you can't.

Comment: Rails automatically stores the last modified date in a table. So you can sort on that and get the first record.

Comment: The `find_by` seems wrong, maybe you need to do `Subscriber.find_by(phone_number: params[:phone_number])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always get the last updated item like this:

```
Subscriber.order('updated_at desc').first
```

But `:updated_at` will update even if anything other than `:visit` is updated. So you have to write a little migration to add a custom field which will do the work for us.

```
rails g migration AddLastVistedToSubscriber last_visited:datetime
```

Run rake `db:migrate` to add `:last_visited` to our table. Now we need to update that field whenever we're doing +1 to `:visit`.

```
def visit
  @subscriber = Subscriber.find_by(params[:phone_number])
  if @subscriber
    @subscriber.visit ||= 0
    @subscriber.visit += 1
    if @subscriber.save
      @subscriber.touch(:last_visited) #this will update the last_visited with the update time
      flash[:notice] = flash[:notice] = "Thank You #{@subscriber.first_name}. You have #{@subscriber.days_till_expired} until renewal"
      redirect_to subscribers_search_path(:subscriber)
    end
  else
    render "search"
  end
end
```

Now we can search easily which `subscriber`'s `:visit` was incremented last.

```
Subscriber.order('last_visited desc').first
```

Comment: Cheer! Glad I could help.

Comment: In 5.1+ you can now add a callback like `before_save :do_something, if: :will_save_change_to_attribute?`